# asp.net mvc datetime format in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jQuery datetime picker.

This is the property of the model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DisplayName("Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY)")]
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

The code in the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.BirthDate, new { @class = "dpTextBox" })
```

some javascript:

```
$(".dpTextBox").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']);
```

In Internet Explorer, it works fine.
In Chrome it doesn't.
The validation error is "The field Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY) must be a date."
The language of Chrome is English.
When I change the language to Dutch, it works fine, but I want the UI of Chrome in English...

Answer (score 1):

```
@{Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.BlogDate)
                    .Name("BlogDate")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "DatePicker_wrapper" })
                    .OpenOnFocus(true)
                    .Render();              
            }
```

use Telerik datepicker

Comment: Why do you propose to use 3rd party library only for datepicker?

Comment: I'd consider down voting this due to the lack of response to the question.  At a minimum this ought to be clarified to be a CLEARLY defined alternative to the original posters question.

Answer (score 0):

When I delete the following piece of code, it works fine...

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

It has something to do with this library